# Unable to get my PHP Form Mailer to work

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP scripts, so when I decided to have an 'Order Form' on my site, I started with an 'off the  shelf' (ie, Googled and started with someone else’s code) form and edited it. However, I can't get it to post any emails to me. My form code looks like this (I will post an image when my REP points are high enough):

```
<form action="form.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="60"> <font color=red>*</font><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="Address" value="" size="58"> <font color=red>*</font><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="" size="60"> <font color=red>*</font><br><br>
Campaign No: <input type="text" name="BookNumber" value="" size="2"> <font color=red>*</font><br><br>
<table border=1><tr><td>Page No. </td><td>Product No. </td><td>Product Name </td><td>Shade/Fragrance </td><td>QTY </td><td>Unit Price </td><td>Total Price </td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item1Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number1" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product1" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance1" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY1" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice1" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice1" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item2Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number2" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product2" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance2" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY2" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice2" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice2" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item3Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number3" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product3" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance3" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY3" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice3" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice3" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item4Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number4" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product4" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance4" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY4" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice4" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice4" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item5Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number5" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product5" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance5" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY5" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice5" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice5" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item6Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number6" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product6" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance6" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY6" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice6" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice6" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item7Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number7" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product7" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance7" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY7" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice7" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice7" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item8Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number8" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product8" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance8" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY8" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice8" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice8" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item9Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number9" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product9" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance9" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY9" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice9" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice9" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item10Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number10" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product10" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance10" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY10" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice10" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice10" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="Item11Page" value="" size="3">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Number11" value="" size="5">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Product11" value="" size="50">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Fragrance11" value="" size="15">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="QTY11" value="" size="2">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Uprice11" value="" size="6">
</td><td>
    <input type="text" name="Tprice11" value="" size="6">
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=6 align=right>Order Processing Charge</td><td align=right>$0.80</td></tr>
</table>


<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

My PHP script looks like this. I assume (being I have used a template and changed it) I have accidentally deleted the wrong line or have a variable not defined properly:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email_out'])) {
    if(!isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Address'])) 
    $email = $_POST['Name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['Address']; // required
    $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $email = $_POST['BookNumber'];     
    $email = $_POST['Item1Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number1'];
    $email = $_POST['Product1'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance1'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY1'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice1'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice1'];
    $email = $_POST['Item2Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number2'];
    $email = $_POST['Product2'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance2'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY2'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice2'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice2'];
    $email = $_POST['Item3Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number3'];
    $email = $_POST['Product3'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance3'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY3'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice3'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice3'];
    $email = $_POST['Item4Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number4'];
    $email = $_POST['Product4'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance4'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY4'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice4'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice4'];
    $email = $_POST['Item5Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number5'];
    $email = $_POST['Product5'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance5'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY5'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice5'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice5'];
    $email = $_POST['Item6Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number6'];
    $email = $_POST['Product6'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance6'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY6'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice6'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice6'];
    $email = $_POST['Item7Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number7'];
    $email = $_POST['Product7'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance7'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY7'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice7'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice7'];
    $email = $_POST['Item8Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number8'];
    $email = $_POST['Product8'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance8'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY8'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice8'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice8'];
    $email = $_POST['Item9Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number9'];
    $email = $_POST['Product9'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance9'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY9'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice9'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice9'];
    $email = $_POST['Item10Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number10'];
    $email = $_POST['Product10'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance10'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY10'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice10'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice10'];
    $email = $_POST['Item11Page'];     
    $email = $_POST['Number11'];
    $email = $_POST['Product11'];
    $email = $_POST['Fragrance11'];
    $email = $_POST['QTY11'];
    $email = $_POST['Uprice11'];
    $email = $_POST['Tprice11'];
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$address)) {
    $error_message .= 'The address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($Name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($Address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "BookNumber: ".clean_string($BookNumber)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item1Page: ".clean_string($Item1Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number1: ".clean_string($Number1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product1: ".clean_string($Product1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance1: ".clean_string($Fragrance1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY1: ".clean_string($QTY1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice1: ".clean_string($Uprice1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice1: ".clean_string($Tprice1)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item2Page: ".clean_string($Item2Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number2: ".clean_string($Number2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product2: ".clean_string($Product2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance2: ".clean_string($Fragrance2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY2: ".clean_string($QTY2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice2: ".clean_string($Uprice2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice2: ".clean_string($Tprice2)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item3Page: ".clean_string($Item3Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number3: ".clean_string($Number3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product3: ".clean_string($Product3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance3: ".clean_string($Fragrance3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY3: ".clean_string($QTY3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice3: ".clean_string($Uprice3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice3: ".clean_string($Tprice3)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item4Page: ".clean_string($Item4Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number4: ".clean_string($Number4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product4: ".clean_string($Product4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance4: ".clean_string($Fragrance4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY4: ".clean_string($QTY4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice4: ".clean_string($Uprice4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice4: ".clean_string($Tprice4)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item5Page: ".clean_string($Item5Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number5: ".clean_string($Number5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product5: ".clean_string($Product5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance5: ".clean_string($Fragrance5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY5: ".clean_string($QTY5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice5: ".clean_string($Uprice5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice5: ".clean_string($Tprice5)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item6Page: ".clean_string($Item6Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number6: ".clean_string($Number6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product6: ".clean_string($Product6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance6: ".clean_string($Fragrance6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY6: ".clean_string($QTY6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice6: ".clean_string($Uprice6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice6: ".clean_string($Tprice6)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item7Page: ".clean_string($Item7Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number7: ".clean_string($Number7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product7: ".clean_string($Product7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance7: ".clean_string($Fragrance7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY7: ".clean_string($QTY7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice7: ".clean_string($Uprice7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice7: ".clean_string($Tprice7)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item8Page: ".clean_string($Item8Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number8: ".clean_string($Number8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product8: ".clean_string($Product8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance8: ".clean_string($Fragrance8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY8: ".clean_string($QTY8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice8: ".clean_string($Uprice8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice8: ".clean_string($Tprice8)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item9Page: ".clean_string($Item9Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number9: ".clean_string($Number9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product9: ".clean_string($Product9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance9: ".clean_string($Fragrance9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY9: ".clean_string($QTY9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice9: ".clean_string($Uprice9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice9: ".clean_string($Tprice9)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item10Page: ".clean_string($Item10Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number10: ".clean_string($Number10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product10: ".clean_string($Product10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance10: ".clean_string($Fragrance10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY10: ".clean_string($QTY10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice10: ".clean_string($Uprice10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice10: ".clean_string($Tprice10)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Item11Page: ".clean_string($Item11Page)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Number11: ".clean_string($Number11)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Product11: ".clean_string($Product11)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Fragrance11: ".clean_string($Fragrance11)."\n";
    $email_message .= "QTY11: ".clean_string($QTY11)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Uprice11: ".clean_string($Uprice11)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Tprice11: ".clean_string($Tprice11)."\n";
mail("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", "Website form submission", $email_message, ""); 
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=welcome.html">
</head>
<body>
Thankyou for your order.<br><br>This page will automatically refresh.
</body>
</html>
```

The little bit of HTML at the end is my confirmation acknowledgement and is the only bit that seems to work properly.

The email TO tag 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net' is required by GoDaddy to accept and relay my email (according to GoDaddy) as part of their PHP processing.

Before someone comes and says I can do it without PHP and use straight HTML, I know this can be done. However HTML posts to an email client, and I want to ensure people who use mobile devices or do not use email clients (eg. use Gmail via a browser) can also use this form.

Comment: You are assigning all values to the same variable! So first `$email` gets the value of `$_POST['name']`, then the value of `$_POST['Address']` etc. Overall the PHP code looks like you should start with reading a few good books about PHP before attempting this. It is an order form, so there is business involved, so this should be taken seriously.

Comment: What are all of the `$email = $_POST['...'];` lines about?

Comment: They were in the original script and I have changed the values to match my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to mail() function is To: email address and I see hostname in your sample.

Also, consider using array with all these form elements and iterating over it when showing the form and getting its data - it will make the code much more readable, I believe

Comment: As stated at the end of my question, GoDaddy's servers use the server when processing PHP and CGI email posts. It's just what their site says. Also, what do you mean by an array?

Comment: I have marked this as my accepted answer since the suggestion of using an Array fixed my problems. However I have expanded my outcome in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since the comments field is limited in it's features, I have stated my changes here. As suggested, I found some books and did some reading. I used a new template and an Array as suggested by @DirkMcQuickly and @Alexey respectively. My new code looks as below (with my actual email removed for privacy):

```
<?php 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $to = "toaddress@address.com";
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Order Submission"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name"; 
 $fields{"Address"} = "Address"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 
 $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"BookNumber"} = "Book Number"; 
 $fields{"Item1Page"} = "Page Number1"; 
 $fields{"Number1"} = "Product Number1"; 
 $fields{"Product1"} = "Product1"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance1"} = "Fragrance1"; 
 $fields{"Uprice1"} = "Unit Price1"; 
 $fields{"Tprice1"} = "Total Price1"; 
 $fields{"Item2Page"} = "Page Number2"; 
 $fields{"Number2"} = "Product Number2"; 
 $fields{"Product2"} = "Product2"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance2"} = "Fragrance2"; 
 $fields{"Uprice2"} = "Unit Price2"; 
 $fields{"Tprice2"} = "Total Price2"; 
 $fields{"Item3Page"} = "Page Number3"; 
 $fields{"Number3"} = "Product Number3"; 
 $fields{"Product3"} = "Product3"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance3"} = "Fragrance3"; 
 $fields{"Uprice3"} = "Unit Price3"; 
 $fields{"Tprice3"} = "Total Price3"; 
 $fields{"Item4Page"} = "Page Number4"; 
 $fields{"Number4"} = "Product Number4"; 
 $fields{"Product4"} = "Product4"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance4"} = "Fragrance4"; 
 $fields{"Uprice4"} = "Unit Price4"; 
 $fields{"Tprice4"} = "Total Price4"; 
 $fields{"Item5Page"} = "Page Number5"; 
 $fields{"Number5"} = "Product Number5"; 
 $fields{"Product5"} = "Product5"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance5"} = "Fragrance5"; 
 $fields{"Uprice5"} = "Unit Price5"; 
 $fields{"Tprice5"} = "Total Price5"; 
 $fields{"Item6Page"} = "Page Number6"; 
 $fields{"Number6"} = "Product Number6"; 
 $fields{"Product6"} = "Product6"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance6"} = "Fragrance6"; 
 $fields{"Uprice6"} = "Unit Price6"; 
 $fields{"Tprice6"} = "Total Price6"; 
 $fields{"Item7Page"} = "Page Number7"; 
 $fields{"Number7"} = "Product Number7"; 
 $fields{"Product7"} = "Product7"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance7"} = "Fragrance7"; 
 $fields{"Uprice7"} = "Unit Price7"; 
 $fields{"Tprice7"} = "Total Price7"; 
 $fields{"Item8Page"} = "Page Number8";  
 $fields{"Number8"} = "Product Number8"; 
 $fields{"Product8"} = "Product8"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance8"} = "Fragrance8"; 
 $fields{"Uprice8"} = "Unit Price8"; 
 $fields{"Tprice8"} = "Total Price8"; 
 $fields{"Item9Page"} = "Page Number9"; 
 $fields{"Number9"} = "Product Number9"; 
 $fields{"Product9"} = "Product9"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance9"} = "Fragrance9"; 
 $fields{"Uprice9"} = "Unit Price9"; 
 $fields{"Tprice9"} = "Total Price9"; 
 $fields{"Item10Page"} = "Page Number10"; 
 $fields{"Number10"} = "Product Number10"; 
 $fields{"Product10"} = "Product10"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance10"} = "Fragrance10"; 
 $fields{"Uprice10"} = "Unit Price10"; 
 $fields{"Tprice10"} = "Total Price10"; 
 $fields{"Item11Page"} = "Page Number11"; 
 $fields{"Number11"} = "Product Number11"; 
 $fields{"Product11"} = "Product11"; 
 $fields{"Fragrance11"} = "Fragrance11"; 
 $fields{"Uprice11"} = "Unit Price11"; 
 $fields{"Tprice11"} = "Total Price11"; 

 $body = "The following is an order from our AVON Web Order Form:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   
 $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 $headers2 = "From: fromaddress@address.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for your order"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for your order. We will contact you when your order is ready for delivery. If you have any questions, feel free to contact us.";

 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: thankyou.html" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please try again later."; } 
 }
}
 ?>
```

This new script even includes a confirmation email and I decided on a dedicated 'thankyou' page with a link instead of embedded HTML tagged on the end like before. Works a treat now! Next I get to see if I am able to format the output.